# Hyperlinks inside UITextView Text Don't Work

Tags: iphone

I am trying to get a hyperlink inside text to work, the text will show up as a hyperlink on the simulator but refuses to be clicked despite the fact I am using the below line:

```
view.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

tl;dr Why can't I click the links inside of my text despite having the same properties set as a million other people.

Comment: Are you using any gesture recognizers?

Comment: @Herly Are you using `UITextField` OR `UITextView` ?